# App contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting "Leaked GCP API Keys" error in my google play console. I have followed this article https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711 . And my key is already restricted but still i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does state: "(Please Note: If you have already added restrictions to your API key, you can ignore this warning.)"

Seems like this is just an issue with the console identifying that those restrictions are in place. Verify your restrictions are set up correctly per the documentation, but this seems to be expected.